# Transfer fuction model

Tags: modeling, model

An electrical circuit comprises a resistance R=1.1ohms in series with an inductance L=1.4H (model Ldi/dt+iR=v). Given that the transfer function model linking voltage supply to current is given as Z=a/(s+b), what is b?

I did Laplace tranform and got (1.4s+1.1)i(s)=V(s), therefore, i(s)=V(s)*1/1.4s+1.1. 
Since Z=a/s+b, then s+b=1.4s+1.1. I got b to be 0.4s+1.1 but it's wrong. Can anyone explain why?

Comment: You have to divide through by 1.4, not simply change the denominator to \$[s+(0.4s+1.1)]\$

Comment: ... although, strictly, there's nothing wrong with your answer, unless the question said that b should be a number.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Consider,
$$ Z(s)= \frac{1}{1.4s+1.1} $$

$$ Z(s)= \frac{0.72}{s+0.78} $$

therefore,

b=0.78, a=0.72